# Independent Probability via Indirect Method

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$A$, $B$, and $C$ have $10\%$, $20\%$ and $30\%$ chance of independently solving a certain math problem. If they all try independently of one another, what is the probability that this group will solve the problem?

Isn't the solution just $0.1 * 0.2 * 0.3$? I don't get why the worksheet says the answer is $1 - (0.9 * 0.8 * 0.7)$. It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: You solved the probability that all of them will get it correct.  What you want is the probability that they don't all get it wrong (somebody gets it correct).  The probability that they don't all get it wrong is $1$ minus the probability that they all get it wrong.

Comment: Because the problem will be solved if at least one of them solves it.

Answer (score 1):

$0.1*0.2*0.3$ is the probability that A solves the problem and B solves the problem and C also solves the problem.  The question is asking for the probability that the group solves the problem and in order for that to happen only one of A, B, or C needs to solve the problem; in other words, the probability that *at least* one of them solves the problem.

The probability of at least one of them solving it is the complement of the probability that none of them solves it; in general, $P(\text{at least one}) = 1 - P(\text{none})$.

$0.9 * 0.8 * 0.7$ is the probability that none of them solves it (the probability that A does not solve the problem and B does not solve the problem and neither does C).  Take the complement and you have your solution:

$$P(\text{A or B or C solves the problem}) =  1 - (0.9 * 0.8 * 0.7) $$